# get specific data in different time period in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
--------------------------------
|name    | time | city |value  | 
--------------------------------
|a       | 2018| rasht | 1.5   |
--------------------------------
|a       | 2017| rasht | 2     |
--------------------------------
|a       | 2018| tehran| 4     |
--------------------------------
|a       | 2017| rasht | 3     |
--------------------------------
|a       | 2018| rasht | 5     |
--------------------------------
|a       | 2017| rasht | 2     |
--------------------------------
|b       | 2018| tehran| 7     |
--------------------------------
```

i like to get data from this table like this:

```
name | city | total 2018 | total 2017
a    |rasht | 6.5        |7
a    |theran| 4          |0
b    |theran| 7          |0
```

I am using query like this:

```
select A.name,city,A.sum(value) ,B.sum(value) from
(select * from tbl where year=2018 group by name,city)A,
(select * from tbl where year=2017 group by name,city)B
where A.name=B.name and A.city=B.city
```

but it didn't work and for records like b that dont have value in 2017 it returns nothing

As u can see my example here is very simple i made exact db in fiddle if u can see it in this address [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aae86jDmdwAzLA7fchUSG/0)

I also use this code:

```
 select subzone, mvFeederName, SUM(CASE WHEN faultStartDate >= 13970901 and faultEndDate <= 13971101 and (subzone=10 ) THEN energyLost ELSE 0 END) AS `unplannedCurrentEnergyLost`, SUM(CASE WHEN faultStartDate >= 13960901 and faultEndDate <= 13961101 and (subzone=10 ) THEN energyLost ELSE 0 END) AS `unplannedLastYearEnergyLost`, count(CASE WHEN faultStartDate >= 13970901 and faultEndDate <= 13971101 and (subzone=10 ) THEN mvFeederName ELSE 0 END) AS `unplannedCurrentCount`, count(CASE WHEN faultStartDate >= 13960901 and faultEndDate <= 13961101 and (subzone=10 ) THEN mvFeederName ELSE 0 END) AS `unplannedLastYearCount` from faults_mv group by subzone,mvFeederName
```

it return zero for energyLost sumation col in two time period and count of mvFeederName  in two thime period is the same that is not correct.

Comment: This is essentially a display issue and, as such, is, to my mind, best resolved in application code.

Comment: I would advise storing data in anything other than the formats recognised by sql. Just do the conversions in your application code.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation -

```
select name, city, 
       sum(case when time=2018 then value end) 'total 2018',
       sum(case when time=2017 then value end) 'total 2017'
from tablename
group by name, city
```

Comment: thanks for answering. i will test it.but i have another problem. if we have product like c that have no values in 2018 and 2017 how can i return it in output table with zero in two time period.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the result you want:

```
SELECT name, city,
    SUM(CASE WHEN time = 2018 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS `total 2018`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN time = 2017 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS `total 2017`
FROM tbl
GROUP BY name, city
```

Output:

```
name    city    total 2018  total 2017
a       rasht   6.5         7
a       tehran  4           0
b       tehran  7           0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ayjRVZcGtbduXb3nfXRBdc/0)

Comment: thanks for replay. i made my db very simple. your answer is correct about that but i modified it for my table and add sum other conditions to it. but it return an odd result .I made an example here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aae86jDmdwAzLA7fchUSG/0 u can see. the sum of energy lost are zero in 2 time period and count return same value for two time period. i save time in jalali format and store it without slashes in faultStartDate and faultEndDate

Comment: mvFeederName can be the same in different subzone( or city)(i gave a subzone code for eache city name that stored in utf-8 persian character) and i want return count for each subzone

Comment: @hsoft the reason you are getting no energyLost values is because you have `and (subzone = 10)` in your `case` expressions. The reason the `count` isn't working is because you always give it a value to count, when you don't want to count you should use `NULL` so don't have an `ELSE` clause on your `case` expression. And the reason that the last year columns are 0 is because there is no data in your fiddle from that year. See my updated fiddle, I think it resolves most of your issues: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aae86jDmdwAzLA7fchUSG/1

Comment: thanks. i will check it. but about subzone =10 the table in example is part of a very big table with 5 city data each city has code by subzone. i think whn i copied data the city with subzone=10 was not in my selection. but i run this code on my complete table and get the same response